# Cant get the html dom by php curl.

Tags: php, curl

I have used php CURL to get the html or echo the html. But it is suddenky redirecting, when i am trying with this code.

```
    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");  
    $ch = curl_init(); 

  function get_data( $ch, $url, $post, $cookie ){
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7"; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    if( $post != '' ) 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    return curl_exec($ch); 
  }
  $url = 'https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/webcivil/FCASSearch?param=I';
  $html = get_data( $ch, $url, '', '' );
  echo $html; exit;
```

I have played with these

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE
```

But still i got redirection when trying to get the html. How can i get the  HTML of the page or is there any other thing try ?

Comment: Do you see where that URL leads?

Comment: Yes, It is redirect to "http://localhost/webcivil/FCASSearch?param=I", Because i am trying in the localhost.

Comment: Try using DOMDocument to get HTML from a url

$url = "http://www.amazon.in/s/url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=".$keywords;

 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0'); /* new dom element */

 @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);  /* load html content */

Comment: I am trying by using php cURL. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed working code to grab the code of the page.

```
  $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");  
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  function get_data( $curl, $url, $post, $cookie ){
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7"; 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    if( $post != '' ) 
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    return curl_exec($curl); 
  }
  $url = 'https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/webcivil/FCASSearch?param=I';
  $html = get_data( $ch, $url, '', '' );
  echo htmlspecialchars($html);
```

But have you seen what you get on this? Almost only JS
which doesnt seem to be very usefull to parse.

Comment: Why you changed the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to flase, although it has https in the URL ?

Comment: Yep, working for me on local server. Before fix i got the same redirect like you to localhost/FCS... But first, llook at the source of the website. Do you think you can use it without first run the JS?

Comment: The verifypeer to false is actually the change which makes it working on my local server. I had the problem once when trying login into a game and for some reason I also had to make similar changes to make it work.

Comment: I have used the same thing in my localhost, But get the same problem. What do you mean first run the JS. I am trying to do it by PHP curl

Comment: Do you use the exact same code? Does the folder "tmp" exist and does it have the needed rights? Also it seems like the

Comment: Yes, i have used the same code. And i have used the same thing to call another page, which was no error.

Comment: Even i changed the network. But dont work for me. I have used the same, exact same code.

Comment: Also tried to change the user agent? This seems to make a difference too in this case.

Comment: Yes i have checked your comment, I have changed to this $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7";

Comment: But, i have another question, where did you declare the $curl variable ? Why did you need to change that ?

Comment: And can we talk in chat, If you have time ?

Comment: Just wanted to be sure that theres no conflic going on. Try the echo with htmlspecialchars() (Just copy the code 1:1 which i edited in the post). It is clearly working here from 2 local servers in same network. If it doesnt work for you i dont know sorry :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125878/discussion-between-ranjit-and-koalagangsta).

Answer (score 0):

You can take idea from this code. Give a path to page from which you want to get html content in live_url.

```
$live_url = "http://www.example.com/page/header.php";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $live_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$res = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Can you try your code by using this url "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/webcivil/FCASSearch?param=I". I have used your code but it is redirect too.

Comment: Give path to file. If its not working then there might be problem in your file in which you are requesting.

Comment: I have a url that is "https://iapps.courts.state.ny.us/webcivil/FCASSearch?param=I". There is no file.

Comment: If you simply want to get the html, then you can use DOMDOCUMENT. Refer to this link http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: I have tried that also. But that is also not working.